# How to draw the vertical link to connect the leading icon in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to draw the vertical line between the leading icon in listtile flutter. I have try VerticalDivider but I don't want the space between the line. I want to do like the image I show below. Does anyone know how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: Text('Name'),
            leading: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
          
ListTile(
        dense: true,
        title: Text('Name'),
        leading: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
      
ListTile(
        dense: true,
        title: Text('Name'),
        leading: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
   
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ],
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines), will be easier to achieve:

for icon indicator, use TimelineNode

```
SizedBox(
height: 80.0,
child: TimelineNode(
indicator: Icon(Icons.people),
startConnector: SolidLineConnector(),
endConnector: SolidLineConnector(),
),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap icons to stack
and add 2  red container to stack with positioned center top and center bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Try out [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) Package,You can draw vertical lines between Stars.**

```html
SizedBox(
  height: 20.0,
  child: DecoratedLineConnector(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.lightBlueAccent[100]],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```